# EmberJS - Get model from another controller in a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, controller

I am trying to get a model from another controller in my route. But it always seems to return null (even though it is there since I can access it from the application controller itself). I thought I needed to add the needs property but that doesn't make a difference.

Am I forgetting something?

```
App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    needs: ['application'], 

    setupController: function(controller, model)
     {
        // Make sure the user is logged in
        if(!this.controllerFor("application").get("isSignedIn"))
        {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }   
        else {
            console.log(this.controllerFor('application').get('model'));
        }       
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have a failing bin? Have you tried this.modelFor('application')

Comment: It would be better if you setup an http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ where you isolate your problem. By the way, controllerFor can always be called, you should ensure that the controller property has been setup. And `needs` is only used to manage controller dependencies http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/